# Align large text with icon

Tags: html, css

I have a `font-awesome` icon and a big text. Now, the second line (and the others) starts right under the icon, but I want that it starts under first letter. How can I set alignement?
This is link to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tuditemiwi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wabimonuvu/1/ like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this in your css: **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wabimonuvu/1)**

```
li i{
  margin-left:-25px; 
  padding:0 5px;
}
```